# Java Android WebView - how to launch javascript function from a separate .js file?

Tags: java, javascript, android, webview

I don't know html and javascript and need to start some certain function from javascript.

I've found that you can start some javascript function simply by myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:function()"); if it's within html. But I've got a bunch of htmls in my raw folder and a separate script.js file which works with all that htmls. I need to start a function from this script.js - so what do I do for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your javascript.js file in the same folder (raw) as your html files are. Then inside the `<head>` tag of your html files import your javascript files (if it is imported already, check if the `src` path inside the `<script>` tag is correct), something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js" ></script>
```

Doing so, you load in your html, all the javascript functions contained in your javascript.js file and you can call `myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:function()");` successfully.